# Can't satisfy DJI E300 ESC with my PWM signal

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, motor-controller, drone

I'm trying to build a drone with my Raspberry Pi 3. I'm using Windows 10 IoT and C#.

I've bought a [DJI E300](https://www.dji.com/e300) pack (motor + ESC + Propeller) and in the [data sheet](http://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/tuned-propulsion-system/e300/en/E300_User_Manual_v1.00_en.pdf) it says that the ESC works with signals in 30 to 450 Hertz. It also says that if you hear a single Beep on an interval (which I'm hearing) it means that the input signal is abnormal.

This is how I'm providing the signal:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    PwmPin motorPin;
    PwmController pwmController;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
        {
            LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
        }

        pwmController = (await PwmController.GetControllersAsync(LightningPwmProvider.GetPwmProvider()))[1];
        motorPin = pwmController.OpenPin(21);
        pwmController.SetDesiredFrequency(50);
        motorPin.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0);
        motorPin.Start();
    }

    private void M1_Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        M1_Label.Text = $"M1 ({e.NewValue})";
        motorPin.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(((double)e.NewValue / 100.0));
    }
}
```

First I used this code to dim a LED and it worked, so I know that the PWM is working fine. But I don't know what else is required for the ESC to work.

Comment: **says that the ESC works with signals in 30 to 450 Hertz.**  So what frequency are you sending?

Answer (score 1):

The ESC almost certainly comes from the RC plane heritage, which means that it's not designed to respond to the average on-time of the PWM, but rather that it expects a 1ms to 2ms pulse.

Moreover, most ESCs are designed with the assumption that there's a human holding a transmitter.  They won't arm unless the PWM is below some threshold (usually 1.1 to 1.2ms).

To make such an ESC work, your PWM needs to do the following:

- Choose a rate.  The original radios ran at a frame rate of 50-60Hz.
- Control the PMW by on time.  1ms is 0% throttle, 2ms is 100% throttle.  The ESC may use a narrower range (i.e. 1.1 - 1.9ms).
- Start at 0% throttle (1ms pulses) for as long as it takes for the ESC to be happy.  This is probably a second or so.

Comment: I wish you could show me these steps in code

Comment: I'm using 50Hz and my initial value for PWM signal is 0 (as you can see in the code above)

Comment: I would suggest a search on "drive a servo from Raspberry Pi".  The ESC thinks its a servo.